# R -- Creating a matrix of line plots using pairs

Tags: r, plot, line-plot

Let's say I have some deterministic data:

```
a<-matrix(c(1:33,exp(1:33/11),(1:33)^2),nrow=33)
```

I want to plot the three columns of data against each other, so I choose to use `pairs()`:

```
pairs(a)
```

This works well enough but I'd like line plots instead of scatter plots. So I try to put in the argument `type='l'` but I get an error:

```
pairs(a,type='l')

Error in plot.default(...) : 
  formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

What is going wrong? How would I be able to get the pictures as line plots instead of scatter plots using `pairs()`? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `panel` arguement!

```
pairs(a, panel = lines)
```

You can further modify the output by exploring the arguments in the help section:

```
?pairs()
```